# How to send 1 email to multiple recipients on SendGrid using the TO field?

Tags: php, email, sendgrid

Based on SendGrid documentation here https://sendgrid.com/docs/Classroom/Send/v3_Mail_Send/personalizations.html#-Sending-the-same-Email-to-Multiple-Recipients

one email sent to Multiple TOs will result in:

> These recipients will all be able to see each other on the email.

Other than this, you can use BCC to send your emails, in order to bypass recipient A to see the email address of recipient B etc.

So if you have 5000 emails and you want the recipient to get it by viewing only his email address on `To` is to make a loop on your code, and send 5000 calls to SendGrid.

This question came out of mind when I saw the Crunchbase newsletter.

Is this something I am missing here?

```
{
  "personalizations": [{
      "to": [{
          "email": "recipient1@example.com"
      }, {
          "email": "recipient2@example.com"
      }, {
          "email": "recipient3@example.com"
      }],
      "substitutions": {
          "%fname%": "recipient",
          "%CustomerID%": "CUSTOMER ID GOES HERE"
      },
      "subject": "YOUR SUBJECT LINE GOES HERE"
  }]
}
```

[image]

Comment: You could try to create a separate personalization object for each recipient. In theory they should not see each other in this case.

Comment: Comment from @Sebastian-LaurenţiuPlesciuc was what I was looking for ... no BCC setup necessary if using a separate personalization for each email address, even if it's just an array of `{ to: email }` it will not show the other emails in the To field for recipients. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

`personalizations` is a list, split the recipients there, not inside `to`. i.e.

```
{
    'personalizations': [
        {'to': [{'email': 'foo@bar.com', 'name': 'Foo'}]},
        {'to': [{'email': 'bar@foo.com', 'name': 'Bar'}]}
    ]
}
```